# Why db storage is shared between all MariaDB containers?

Tags: docker, mariadb

I have come across some weird behavior on Mac regarding Docker containers that I create for MariaDB. The issues occur each time I create a MariaDB container with a command like the following:

```
 docker run --rm --name db1 --publish 3307:3306   --mount type=volume,source=dbvol,target=/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test  mariadb
```

I see two weird things:
- First, I don't need to provide any user or password to log into the server running on 3307. I can easily log in as root with "mysql -P 3307"!
- Second, although for each new container I create e.g. db1, db2, db3, etc. I create a new volume with `docker volume create dbvol[dbvol2,dbvol3,etc.]`, the db storage seems to be shared for all containers. So, when inside db2 I can see all tables and data I added in db1 and vice versa.

Could anyone explain this please?  I am confused. Is this a bug or there is something about container volumes that I don't know?

PS.

Just discovered that homebrew version of mysql client does not respect the P (port) flag. It opens my local host database in fact. I thought it was using the container database.

Answer (score 1):

It seems all your containers are running with a volume called dbdata: although you created `dbvol{1,2,3}`, you have to specify it on the `source` of your mount - a different one for each instance:

```sh
docker run --rm --name db1 --publish 3307:3306 --mount type=volume,source=dbvol1,target=/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test mariadb
```

```sh
docker run --rm --name db3 --publish 3308:3306 --mount type=volume,source=dbvol2,target=/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test mariadb
```

```sh
docker run --rm --name db2 --publish 3309:3306 --mount type=volume,source=dbvol3,target=/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test mariadb
```

When source is a name of a volume that does not exist, it is automatically created for you. You can read more about the mounts [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#add-bind-mounts-volumes-or-memory-filesystems).

About the user/password for logging in: did you do that right away after starting the container? Because when the container first starts it runs an initialization process, and then restarts the server, then all permissions should be fine.

Comment: Just edited the post. Changed dbdata to dbvol. Makes no difference really what I call the data volume. It seems to be using the same storage all the time.

Comment: Did you run each container with a different volume source? I edited the answer to make it more clear

Comment: Yes I do. Still Docker seems to be using a common storage for all of them.

Comment: Just updated the post. Seems like it is my host database that opens. It is not the docker database.

Comment: Are you sure? If you create a file inside one container, does it appear in the others? You can do that with `touch /var/lib/mysql/a` inside a container, and checking if the `a` file appeared on other containers. My tests seem to indicate they should not be shared. You can also check the `Mounts` key in `docker inspect db{1,2,3}` to check the  name/source of the volumes.

Comment: Oh, that's another issue then. You can test by running `mysql` inside the containers with `docker exec -ti db1 mysql --password`